# Slice and extract specific values from JSON output

Tags: python, json, slice

I am querying a REST API and I need to select 2 fields from the adapter output below, the query will include multiple incident numbers.

I basically need a list of Incident Numbers and Descriptions from the output below.

Code to get the data:

```
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Authentication-Token': authToken}
response = requests.post('http://dev.startschools.local:2031/baocdp/rest/process/:ITSM_Interface:IncidentManagement:QueryIncident/execute', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(get_query_inc_json()))
 
print(response.text)
```

response.text printed Output:

```
[{"name":"Adapter_Output","value":"<query-action-result><entries><metadata><entry-count>2</entry-count></metadata><entry id=\"INC000003197686|INC000003197686\"><field name=\"Incident Number\">INC000021</field><field name=\"Description\">Student needs a new card issued</field></entry><entry id=\"INC000003198967|INC000003198967\"><field name=\"Incident Number\">INC000035</field><field name=\"Description\">Students cannot access the text book portal</field></entry></entries></query-action-result>"}]
```

I need to get a list of Incident numbers and descriptions so I can loop through them:

List 1 of incident numbers:

```
["INC000021", "INC000035"]
```

List 2 of Descriptions:

```
["Student needs a new card issued", "Students cannot access the text book portal"]
```

I am trying to use slice to get all the incident numbers into a list but because the output keeps changing the slice is not working.

Anyone know of a more efficient way other than slice to extract the info I need from this output?

Comment: Please add the code you are currently using. You can use something like beautiful soup library for this.

Comment: `response.text` is a string; you need to use `json.loads(response.text)` to *decode* the string into a Python `dict`, or use `response.json()` to get a pre-decoded version of the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
data = response.text

value = data[0]["value"]
i_nums = [x.split("</field")[0] for x in value.split('<field name=\"Incident Number\">')[1:]]
desc = [x.split("</field")[0] for x in value.split('<field name=\"Description\">')[1:]]

print(i_nums)
print(desc)
```

Comment: `data` is a string, not a list of dicts.

Comment: This is awesome, chepner was correct, needed to use json.load and then your solution worked perfect. Thanks @jjislam

Answer (score 1):

Even though @jjislam's answer gives you the right answer for your example, I would recommend you to make use of a proper xml parser to navigate through your result, because this is the actual intent of having structured data in the first place!

This is a snippet on how to use the built-in `xml.etree` package. Once you get what is going on here, you can easily convert it into a single-liner with comprehensions.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree

responseText = [{"name":"Adapter_Output","value":"<query-action-result><entries><metadata><entry-count>2</entry-count></metadata><entry id=\"INC000003197686|INC000003197686\"><field name=\"Incident Number\">INC000021</field><field name=\"Description\">Student needs a new card issued</field></entry><entry id=\"INC000003198967|INC000003198967\"><field name=\"Incident Number\">INC000035</field><field name=\"Description\">Students cannot access the text book portal</field></entry></entries></query-action-result>"}]

# the root will be the topmost element, in this case the one with tag "query-action-result"
root = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(responseText[0]["value"])
incidents, descriptions = [], []

# iterate recursively over all elements with tag "entry" that are children of the root element
for entry in root.iter('entry'): 
    # within each entry, find the first element with tag "field" and attribute "name=Incident Number", and capture its content
    incident = entry.find("field[@name='Incident Number']").text
    # same, but with attribute "name=Description"
    description = entry.find("field[@name='Description']").text
    print(incident, description)
    incidents.append(incident)
    descriptions.append(description)

print(incidents)
print(descriptions)
```

Comment: Thanks will try this solution as well. Just need to understand the XML.etree a bit more.

Comment: I added a few comments to help you understand the code